# Laravel dispatch after response appends error to the response

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue

In the Laravel documentation there is this part:

> You may also dispatch a closure and chain the afterResponse method onto the dispatch  helper to execute a closure after the HTTP response has been sent to the browser:
>
> ```
> use App\Mail\WelcomeMessage;
> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
>
> dispatch(function () {
>     Mail::to('taylor@example.com')->send(new WelcomeMessage);
> })->afterResponse();
> ```

This works perfectly fine when the mail is successfully sent. However, when there is an error in the mail sending function, for example, if I intentionally misconfigure the mailing service credentials in .env, then Laravel appends a `{"message": "Server Error" }` to the response.

Here's an excerpt from the actual code:

```
public function register() {
    try {
        dispatch(function () use ($user) {
                   Mail::to($user)->send(new Register($user));
        })->afterResponse();
    } catch (Exception $e) {     
         return response()->json(['success' => true]);
    }

    return response()->json(['success' => true]);

}
```

When the mail succeeds, the JSON data `{success: true}` is returned for the ajax call to process. However, when there is an error in the mail sending part, the following message is returned:

```
{"success":true}{
    "message": "Server Error"
}
```

The try-catch blocks didn't seem to help.

Any ideas why is that message appended to the response data?

Comment: Just tried the same code without the `->afterResponse()` block and the message is not appended. So, the issue is somewhere in the afterResponse chainable.

Comment: it looks like the response is sent but the connection with the client is not closed so any errors are also pushed to the stream. Not sure what you can do about that. Ideally you'd be sending the emails to the queue

Comment: Yeap, seems like the most appropriate solution, to set up a queue for mail sending. There ain't no way to catch exceptions that were thrown in the afterRequest() method.